# How can I change the cell colour in Google Apps Script for each cell individually inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My question is:*How can I change the cell colour in Google Apps Script for each cell individually inside a for loop?

I have a dataset containing several values, grouped by an ID variable, which I'd like to compare with their overall average or median respectively. In the toy example bellow you'll find variable `uniqueValues` which I use as an ID variable and variable `median` which contains the median for each group.

The code I wrote checks my data on two conditions and returns either yes or no. Of course, in Google Apps Script I'd like to change these rather useless outcomes in, for example, a green or red background color. However, this is the part where I failed to succeed countless times. Maybe you could help me overcome this issue.

Here's the code I wrote to see if my idea works as expected – I think it does.

```js
var uniqueValues = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var median = [10, 12, 13, 18];

var data = [["a", "ab", 1, 2, 1, 8],
        ["a", "ab", 1, 4, 5, 9],
        ["a", "ab", 1, 4, 3, 10],
        ["a", "ab", 8, 2, 4, 11],
        ["a", "ab", 3, 3, 1, 12],
        ["b", "bb", 1, 2, 1, 9],
        ["b", "bb", 1, 8, 3, 11],
        ["b", "bb", 10, 2, 1, 12],
        ["b", "bb", 1, 6, 2, 13],
        ["b", "bb", 11, 21, 1, 16],
        ["c", "cb", 1, 6, 11, 9],
        ["c", "cb", 3, 5, 1, 12],
        ["c", "cb", 1, 6, 11, 13],
        ["c", "cb", 7, 8, 1, 14],
        ["c", "cb", 3, 8, 11, 20],
        ["d", "dd", 4, 4, 11, 16],
        ["d", "dd", 1, 1, 2, 17],
        ["d", "dd", 9, 4, 22, 18],
        ["d", "dd", 2, 6, 5, 19],
        ["d", "dd", 4, 3, 1, 29]];

var temp = [];
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {

  data.map(function (outerArray) {
if (outerArray[i] == uniqueValues[i] && outerArray[5] > median[i]) {
  temp.push("yes");
} else if (outerArray[i] == uniqueValues[i] && outerArray[5] <= median[i]) {
  temp.push("no");
}
  });
}
console.log(temp);
```

However, I fail to succeed in Google Apps Script. What I get is a sheet that is coloured completely green. Here's what I tried so far.

```
var summarySheet = workbook.getSheetByName("01Summary");
// this next line is the cause of my trouble I guess!
var rangeToFormat = summarySheet.getRange(3, 1, summarySheet.getLastRow(), summarySheet.getLastColumn());
var dataForFormat = summarySheet.getRange(3, 1, summarySheet.getLastRow(), summarySheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

for (let i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {

  dataForFormat.map(function (outerArray) {
    if (outerArray[i] == uniqueValues[i] && outerArray[6] > medianResults[i]) {
      rangeToFormat.setBackground("red");
    } else if (outerArray[i] == uniqueValues[i] && outerArray[6] <= medianResults[i]) {
      rangeToFormat.setBackground("green");
    }
  });
};
```

I assume my mistake is that I'm using the whole sheet in variable `rangeToFormat` to format. Which is obviously not correct. However, I don't know how to fix that inside my loop. Maybe I need a temporary variable to add to the iterations of my loop? Like `row j + i of loop` or something like that?

Anyway. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this simple example will help you:

```
function randomColors() {
  var colors=['red','orange','yellow','green','blue'];//could be strings like '#ffffff'
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,25,1);
  var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){cA[i][0]=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]});
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

Or with some small tweaks you can go two dimensional

```
function randomcolors2d() {
  var colors=['red','orange','yellow','green','blue'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,25,10);
  var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      cA[i][j]=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
    });
  });
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input Cooper. I'll check your approach tomorrow. Hopefully I'll find a solution for my problem using your valuable insights. If so, I'll accept your answer straight away.